# C# compiling to MSIL code

Tags: c#, cil, csc, intermediate-language

Does the Microsoft C# compiler (CSC.exe) have an option to output the Intermediate Language files? Kind of like the -S switch does in GCC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(VS.71).aspx) to extract the IL from the assembly compiled by csc.exe.

Comment: Thanks for the link @jdk. I updated my answer to link directly there.

Answer (score 6):

Your final executables and DLLs are stored in IL.

To see what I mean, download [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), open one of your DLLs or executables, and switch the language to IL. It will also go through translating the IL into C# for you.

Comment: DLLs aren't stored in IL. They are stored in Byte Code, right?

Comment: There's no such thing as Byte Code with .net.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language, it's a little confusing. CIL and Bytecode are almost the same, either way its being JITed to native code, instead of compiled straight to native bytecode.

Comment: Generally the binary code of virtual machines is called "bytecode", however, the ECMA CLI specification does not really use this term. It's called binary MSIL or binary IL.